# How can I monitor iptables classification applied by OpenWRT QoS, preferably live?

Tags: iptables, openwrt, qos, iftop

I set up a bunch of quality of service rules in OpenWRT, which then are translated to iptables rules. For debugging purposes, I'd love to see how the different connections are binned into, which would be very helpful at understanding my traffic and whether the rules match as expected.

`iftop` might be able to solve the issue with it's filter rules, but I'm unsure how to match the QoS bins using `tcpdump` filters.

The AVM fritz!box user interface has a pretty decent, visualization of traffic binned by QoS levels (picture credits go to [Brandon Davis](http://brendon.davis.to/2012/04/07/fritzbox-qos/)):

[image]

Is it possible to either get a similar diagram using the OpenWRT luci interface or the command line? Filtering `iftop` or `bmon` would be totally fine, too.